# How to print specific word from a text file

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file abc.txt the contents are

{"storageSummary":{"binariesSummary":{"binariesCount":"703","binariesSize":"882.39 MB","artifactsSize":"3.41 GB","optimization":"25.23%","itemsCount":"4,126","artifactsCount":"1,917"},"fileStoreSummary":{"storageType":"file-system","storageDirectory":"/jfrog_uat_nfs/binaries","totalSpace":"1.30 TB","usedSpace":"1.23 GB (0.09%)","freeSpace":"1.30 TB (99.91%)"},"repositoriesSummaryList":[{"repoKey":"sbt_remote-cache","repoType":"CACHE","foldersCount":0,"filesCount":0,"usedSpace":"0 bytes","itemsCount":0,"packageType":"SBT","percentage":"0%"},{"repoKey":"test7.mvlo","repoType":"LOCAL","foldersCount":0,"filesCount":1,"usedSpace":"128 bytes","itemsCount":1,"packageType":"Maven","percentage":"0%"},{"repoKey":"scripttestkp.rplo","repoType":"LOCAL","foldersCount":0,"filesCount":0,"usedSpace":"0 bytes","itemsCount":0,"packageType":"RPM","percentage":"0%"},{"repoKey":"test7.grvr","repoType":"VIRTUAL","foldersCount":0,"filesCount":0,"usedSpace":"0 bytes","itemsCount":0,"packageType":"Gradle","percentage"

From this file how to print only "repoKey" and "usedSpace" in shell script.

Comment: Is this a `json` input?, looks like a broken `JSON` input file, and provide the complete `json` input.

Comment: Use an appropriate `JSON` parser after fixing your input file

Comment: Why do you say the json is wrong, Inian? Seems okay on first glance...  looks like he missed a bit of cut and paste maybe

Comment: @me_: Try placing the input in https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/, to see if it is syntactically right. It isn't

Comment: He obviously missed the last bits of the json in cut and paste...  beyond that it is correct, typo on thos site not incorrect format...

Comment: This is  big file i copied a small part. Actually  this is the output of a curl command. My requirement is from that output  i want repoKey filed and usedSpace fileld.{"repoKey":"test7.mvlo","repoType":"LOCAL","foldersCount":0,"filesCount":1,"usedSpace":"128bytes",

Answer (score -1):

you need to access: data.storageSummary.repositoriesSummaryList[i].repoKey for each i in the list

As well as iterating over everything that has usedSpace as a key...  for example: data.storageSummary.fileStoreSummary.usedSpace and data.storageSummary.repositoriesSummaryList[i].usedSpace for each i

using jq in the commandline of linux boxes, the command to access the first instance of usedSpace is:

```
curl "site" | jq ".storageSummary.fileStoreSummary.usedSpace"
```

output is:

```
"1.23 GB (0.09%)"
```

the command to access the array of values for usedSpace under repoKeys is:

```
curl "site" | jq ".storageSummary.repositoriesSummaryList[].usedSpace"
```

the output is:

```
"0 bytes"
"128 bytes"
"0 bytes"
"0 bytes"
```

the command to access the array of values of repoKey is:

```
curl "site" | jq ".storageSummary.repositoriesSummaryList[].repoKey"
```

the output is:

```
"sbt_remote-cache"
"test7.mvlo"
"scripttestkp.rplo"
"test7.grvr"
```

this can be verified by correcting the json provided so that it is valid then heading on over to https://jqplay.org/